# Why static block are executed later?

Tags: java, static

P.S :

`This question has been edited a few times as my previous code doesn't demonstrate the problem. There are some answers which may not make perfect sense against the edited question`

I have a public class named `Son.java`

```
package com.t;

public class Son extends Father {

    static int i;

    static {
        System.out.println("son - static");
        i = 19;
    }

    {
        System.out.println("son - init-block"); 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Son s = new Son();
        int a[] = new int[2];
        System.out.println(a[5]);
    }

}

class Father {

    static {
        System.out.println("f - static");
    }
    {
        System.out.println("f - init-block");
    }
}
```

When I run the program for the 1st time:

Output is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at com.t.Son.main(Son.java:19)
f - static
son - static
```

And later when I run this program (order of output is `random`)

Output is:

```
f - static
son - static
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 5
    at com.t.Son.main(Son.java:19)
```

I have read that `static` blocks are executed as the classes are initalised.

But why does the exception has come first here and then static block is executed?

I am using `Eclipse` too to run my program.
Can somebody explain?

Comment: The max value of 'a' index in your case is 1. Because arrays have indexes from 0.

Comment: You should really provide a *complete* example which others can try to reproduce the problem.

Comment: To which class the main method belongs to ?

Comment: @David I have removed that.

Comment: @Thinker: that code wouldn't compile. If main() is indeed in the Son class, it should be inside the curly braces of the Son class. And test() is an undefined method.

Comment: @Thinker: It's clearly *not* the complete code. There's no `test` method, and there's no class to which the `main` method belongs. Try copying it into a text editor and then compiling the file - it won't work.

Comment: @DavidWallace: Every potential answerer can reproduce it with a reasonably small amount of effort, yes. However, that doesn't mean that we're reproducing it in the same way as the OP *and* there's no reason for all that duplicate effort when the OP could just have included the complete code to start with. The OP should get into the habit of including short but complete programs to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: @Jon Please see the updated question. I have found one more scenario.

Comment: Thinker - you really shouldn't add a whole lot of stuff to the question after you've already got three answers.  Moreover, now I _know_ there's stuff you missed out.  Which class has "gf - static" in it?

Comment: @Thinker: We haven't even got *one* scenario yet. You still haven't provided a *complete* program. We don't even know what class contains `main`! Please edit your question so there is a piece of code we can simply copy into a text editor, compile, and run. It sounds like you've already *got* that, but for some reason you've decided to cut some of it out of your question :(

Comment: I don't see how the edit would compile too..

Comment: @Thinker: Finally, thank you. Unfortunately it doesn't display the result you've shown when I run it on my computer :(

Comment: I think the behaviour here is undefined.  It's all about which flushes first, out of standard out and standard error.  This is just about guaranteed to be platform-dependent.

Comment: @Thinker: Try using `System.err.println` instead of `System.out.println` and see if you always get the same order.

Comment: @Jon I am sorry. you are right. I have not presented the question in a right way. After removing my other code, output is coming differently. What you will suggest? Should I ask a new question or edit this one?

Comment: Haha, you're not trying to prove me wrong, are you @Keppil ?

Comment: @David: No, I am trying to prove you right. :)

Comment: OK, in that case, I'll allow it.  :-)

Comment: @Thinker: I think you're okay to edit this question to just show the complete code which demonstrated the problem. But include something which explicitly states that it's been edited a few times, to make it clear why some answers may not make perfect sense against the edited question.

Comment: So if you run this program, say 10 times, is it really completely unpredictable which result you get each time?

Comment: @David Yes. I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Well, I think the buffering of standard out and standard error takes place at the operating system level, not within Java.  So that makes this a question about the operating system, not a Java question.  It could come down to what else the operating system happens to be doing at the moment that you run your code.  As per my comment from 07:29:23Z, this is not defined by Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The exception doesn't happen first, you are just seeing the printout of the exception first.

Had the exception happened first, you would never have seen the rest of the output.

The reason for this is that you have output to both `System.err` (from your exception) and `System.out` in your program. The order in which these are printed to the screen is not defined, so therefore you can get them in different order.

Comment: Quite so. The exception prints to stderr whereas the static blocks print to stdout. It outputs in a "random" order because it's up to the mercy of whatever ran the thing to decide which actually hits the console first.

Answer (score 3):

Stack traces of uncaught exceptions are printed in `System.err`, which is an unbuffered stream. You print text to `System.out` which is a buffered stream and it is unpredictable whether it he buffer gets flushed before or after the stack trace is printed.

If you change all your print statements to `System.err` then the order of the output will become the order of printing, and it will always be the same order.

Answer (score 0):

@Keppil's answer has nailed it.

---

I just want to point out something ... erm ... interesting.

The OP says this:

> I am using Eclipse to run my program.

The knee jerk response would be to say "that isn't relevant" ... but in this case, I think it >>is<< relevant.  I suspect that non-determinism in stdout/stderr timing is being is *amplified* by the fact that the output is going to a Eclipse "console" panel.

When an application is run from the command line, output to stderr and stdout probably gets merged into out stream somewhere in the OS kernel.  And if not, the console program probably uses a `select` syscall to handle input from two sources ... and gives one stream priority over the other, 'cos that is the easy way to code it.  As a result, you would expect the output to appear on the console in a mostly consistent order, even though order is non-deterministic.

But when the application writes to an Eclipse console, Eclipse probably uses a separate thread to read each stream.  Assuming that both threads are blocked in `read` syscalls, and input arrives at roughly the same time on both streams, it will be up to the thread scheduler to decide which thread gets woken first.  That is going to be far less predictable that the behaviour of a select ... or of stream merging in the kernel.

Either way, my observation is that reordered stdout / stderr output is more prevalent with an Eclipse console than when you are using a "native" console.

Answer (score -2):

As the asker said `main` belongs to `Son` class and is extending `Father`. I modified the code a little, so I was able to compile.

```
    class Father {
    static{
        System.out.println("f - static");

    }
}

public class Son extends Father {
    static {
        System.out.println("son - static");
    }

public static void main(String[] args) throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException{
        int a[] = new int[2];
        System.out.println(a[3]);
    }
}
```

And the output is:-

```
f - static
son - static
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
    at kanwal.Son.main(Son.java:20)
```

Its working exactly, the way it is supposed to.

**EDIT:-
This answer was made, before OP edited the question.**

Comment: Your answer doesn't explain why the output is sometimes in one order and sometimes in the other order ... which is what the OP is **really** asking about.

Comment: The answer is in accordance with the third edit made by OP. The current version of the question isn't what OP started with. Its mention as note on top of the question.

Comment: Well it certainly doesn't answer the question as it is now.  So as of now, the downvotes are valid.  (Feel free to update your answer ... or to delete it to get back the -4 from the 2 downvotes.  You will of course lose the remaining +6, but that's your choice.)

Comment: I'll let it be, and see how much negative votes this answer could fetch i.e how much wayward my answer to the question is.(Even though the OP has explicitly mentioned it). The answer to the question(as of now) is not within my knowledge. Hence, I didn't edit it.